# How to disable Solr from reordering data

Tags: python, django, solr, django-oscar

Is it possible to disable Solr from moving `selected feacets`(in filter), on first index ?

As for now if i select an element (`product class`) in my menu filter
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5r2Z.png)
(that is being returned from solr search engine)

It return that element on first position - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjWpU.png) , but originaly that element(classic) was on the last position

Is it possible to fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown your Solr query, but most likely you are seeing [facets sorted by the counts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-Thefacet.sortParameter) which change as you narrow your query. You can sort lexicographically instead with **facet.sort=index** parameter.

This parameter can be set in the query or in the solrconfig.xml on the request handler.